# Align UIImageView with UILabel at bottom baseline

Tags: ios, uiimageview, alignment, uilabel, baseline

I want to align the content of the UILabel with the UIImageView at the bottom level BUT, I want this:

[image]

NOT this:

[image]

Comment: The gray square is just the placeholder for the UIImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solved it in the interface builder like this:
[image]

I changed the constraint from bottom to last baseline.